# Webscraping a Javascript React page using Python Selenium on an element that hides after few seconds

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage that has a React element that hides the dropdown after few seconds.

This is what you see when you first get to the page and the tab I would like to scrape.

[image: Dropdown element I want to scrape. Specifically the '24' people are viewing this event line.]

I'm trying to scrape the part that says **Don't miss out! 24 people are viewing this event**

After few seconds, the tab disappears and gets replaced by another dropdown element that says **Get notified at the right price!**

[image: new dropdown that replaces the one i want to scrape. It hides the previous dropdown]

The source code reveals the **view count** drop down as being hidden after few seconds. The top of the code shows the new dropdown while the bottom with the **'hide'** in the div class being the dropdown I want to scrape.

[image: The source code showing the hidden dropdown code]

I've tried getting the **div class = "urgency-component-container** but due to it being hidden, it returns nothing. I've also tried getting the **div class = "dropdown-header-item"** but that was returning nothing as well.

I've tried getting the XPath to the dropdown-header-item (//*[@id="dropdown-header"]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVY4r.jpg)) but that didn't work either.

How can I scrape the dropdown that "hides" after few seconds? Thanks

EDIT:

the website url is :
https://www.stubhub.com/anaheim-ducks-tickets-anaheim-ducks-anaheim-honda-center-11-14-2019/event/104217448/?sort=price%20asc

The code I used was

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.stubhub.com/anaheim-ducks-tickets-anaheim-ducks-anaheim-honda-center-11-14-2019/event/104217448/?sort=price+asc'
driver.get(url)

content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown-header-item')
```

If I execute the code straightaway I get an error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".dropdown-header-item"}
```

but if I wait few seconds and run it then I get

```
Get notified at the right price!Set price alert
```

Comment: Can i get the application url?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @YosuvaA I pasted the url in the body edit

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the info. I've made some edit and added my code

Comment: @uclaastro I have added my answer with sample code and it works fine for me. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and let me know how it goes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'https://www.stubhub.com/anaheim-ducks-tickets-anaheim-ducks-anaheim-honda-center-11-14-2019/event/104217448/?sort=price+asc'
driver.get(url)
driver.refresh()

content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='urgency-wrapper']//div[@class='dropdown-header-item']").text
print content

driver.quit()
```

### output:

> Don't miss out. 28 people are viewing this event.

Comment: I'm getting a blank return. When I print the content it's printing blank

Comment: @uclaastro Looks like that message appear only first time. it is not showing when i ran 2nd time.Also when i checked the html code 2nd time, i couldn't find those tags

Comment: How to get that message again?

Comment: You have to refresh the page

Comment: @uclaastro I have updated my code. can you try now?

Comment: Still getting blank

Comment: Your application is not showing 1st message always. That is the reason you are getting blank instead of text. My code works whenever application shows the 1st message.

Comment: Ok I've tried it again and it seems to be working. There are times where it brings back blank but I think a new refresh would do that. I can probably put in a condition that if it brings a blank result then refresh it. Now the only problem is whether to keep this page for days and refresh it or just start a new browser each time. Having to deal with the captcha is another issue tho. Thanks!

Comment: So I've run it several times and it seems like it's only working the first time page is loaded or after several refreshes have been done. I need to code it so if there's a blank return, then it'll refresh and get the content but your code isn't pulling the content

Comment: So I've created a while loop to keep refreshing it until I get a value so it looks like that part is ok now. Just trying to figure out a way to kill the browser if there's a captcha screen and load the browser again is another issue now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like site doesn't like scraping and throws up captcha for starters. If there wasn't a captcha then you want the .textContent property of the last element matched with class `dropdown-header-item`

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.stubhub.com/anaheim-ducks-tickets-anaheim-ducks-anaheim-honda-center-11-14-2019/event/104217448/?sort=price%20asc')
elems = d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dropdown-header-item')
if len(elems) > 0:
    print(d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dropdown-header-item')[-1].get_attribute('textContent').replace('\xa0', ' '))
else:
    print('Nada')
```

Comment: This returns 'Nada'. I tried printing elems and it's returning a blank result

Comment: Did you observe the loaded page? Did it hit a captcha?